# CSS: centering elements with inline absolute widths/heights

Tags: html, css

I need to vertically and horizontally center multiple elements within a parent. BUT, here's the catch -- both the parent and child have their widths and heights set via inline styles.

```
<div class="parent" style="height:300px;width:300px">
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">These</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">items</div>
</div>
```

I've found multiple solutions for centering online (e.g. via CSS tables). But none of the ones I've tried worked for elements with inline widths/heights.

(I know inline styles are evil, but in this case, it's out of my control).

Here's a rough idea of what it needs to look like (obviously, without the centering):

http://jsfiddle.net/apyex2tu/50/

Thanks!

EDIT:

- The centering, ideally, would be performed via CSS.
- I'd rather avoid flex, since then I'd need to test it with older IE versions (this is a hard requirement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the parent display as table-cell.

```css
.child {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px; margin: 4px auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.parent {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="height:300px;width:300px">
    <div class="child" style="width:60px">These</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:70px">items</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:180px">should be centered</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using table row and table cell you can make it center align vertical and horizontal use table row for patent div and child will be table cell. like below code

```
.child {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:table-row;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to your childs!

Since they are block elements with a fixed width margin auto centers those elements
to center it vertically add a wrapper set its height, position it at 50% and give it a negative margin of half its height!

[A new fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/mvfufaqr/)

Comment: That only centers horizontally.. I think.

Comment: Now it includes a vertically centered solution ;)